# Get unique id using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have following text:

```
This is the foo test the date purchase id is /STAR2015A. This is another foo test the purchase is /STAR2022M. Yet another foo test, get it back by if u dont like, purchase id is /STAR2039K. You wont be surprised if i write another id /STAR2050L.
```

I want to get all the unique purchase ids. It starts with /STAR every time and ends with letter A-M. Also, the number ranges from 2010 - 2050. I tried following but it doesnt return any result:

```
import re
dset = []

text = "This is the foo test the date purchase id is /STAR2015A. This is another foo test the purchase is /STAR2022M. Yet another foo test, get it back by if u dont like, purchase id is /STAR2039K. You wont be surprised if i write another id /STAR2050L. "

pattern = re.findall("[^\/STAR[20][10-50][A-M]]",text)

print(pattern)
```

Let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Maybe [`re.findall(r'/STAR(\w+)', text)`](https://ideone.com/hlgAfp) will do? Then you may use `set` to get the distinct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
/STAR20(?:[1-4]\d|50)[A-M]
```

- `/STAR20` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[1-4]\d` Match 10 - 49
  - `|` or
  - `50` Match 50
- `)` Close group
- `[A-M]` Match A - M

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YRcdmu/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0cKedN)

Example

```
result = re.findall(r"/STAR20(?:[1-4]\d|50)[A-M]", text)
```